# Is there a way to find the batch size for a tf.data.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I understand you can assign a batch size to a Dataset and return a new dataset object. Is there an API to interrogate the batch size given a dataset object?

I am trying to find the calls at:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you call the `.batch(32)` method , it returns an `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset` object. As documented in [Tensorflow Documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e5bf8de410005de06a7ff5393fafdf832ef1d4ad/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L3619) This kind of object has private attribute called `._batch_size` which contain a tensor of batch_size.

In tensorflow 2.X you need just call `.numpy()` method of this tensor to convert it to `numpy.int64` type.
In tensorflow 1.X you need to cal `.eval()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you can just get it as an attribute, but you could just iterate through the dataset once and print the shape:

```
# create a simple tf.data.Dataset with batchsize 3
import tensorflow as tf 
f = tf.data.Dataset.range(10).batch(3) # Dataset with batch_size 3

# iterating once
for one_batch in f:
    print('batch size:', one_batch.shape[0])
    break
```

If you know your dataset has targets/labels as well, you have to iterate as follows:

```
# iterating once
for one_batch_x, one_batch_y in f:
    print('batch size:', one_batch_x.shape[0])
    break
```

In both cases, it will print:

```
batch size:  3
```

Comment: Ok. I was hoping there's some hidden API.

Answer (score 1):

In Tensorflow 1.* access `batch_size` via `dataset._dataset._batch_size`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
print(tf.__version__) # 1.14.0

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)).batch(10)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    batch_size = sess.run(dataset._dataset._batch_size)
    print(batch_size) # 10
```

In Tensorflow 2 you can access via `dataset._batch_size`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
print(tf.__version__) # 2.0.1

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)).batch(10)

batch_size = dataset._batch_size.numpy()

print(batch_size) # 10
```