# Given a dataset, find if it's batch'ed

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I implement function `isBatched` so that it tests if the argument `dataset` is batched?

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)    

def isBatched(dataset):
    # I guess this is what @yudhiesh means
    batch = next(iter(dataset))
    return batch.shape.ndims > 0 and batch.shape[0] > 0

tensor1 = tf.range(100)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor1)

assert isBatched(dataset.batch(10)) == True, "T1 fails"
assert isBatched(dataset.batch(10).map(lambda x: x)) == True, "T2 fails"
assert isBatched(dataset.batch(10).filter(lambda x: True).xxx.yyy.zzz) == True, "T3 fails"
assert isBatched(dataset.repeat()) == False, "T4 fails"

tensor2 = tf.random.uniform([10, 10])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor2)
assert isBatched(dataset) == False, "T5 fails"
```

Don't have to consider .batch().unbatch() cases.

I checked [Is there a way to find the batch size for a tf.data.Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819783/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-batch-size-for-a-tf-data-dataset), which seems to require the last call being .batch(). In my case, .batch can appear anywhere during the call chain.

[How to get batch size back from a tensorflow dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912441/how-to-get-batch-size-back-from-a-tensorflow-dataset) assumes the first dimention is the batch. It doesn't work if the original dataset is multi-dimention.

Please show me code because I'm preparing my lecture for my students tomorrow.

Comment: As `tf.data.Datasets` are iterables you could try running `batch = next(iter(dataset))` and the first call would be true, the second call would be false if it wasn't batched.

Comment: @yudhiesh I updated the question at the same time as you post this comment. What if the original dataset is not 1-dimentional?

Comment: If you are solely working with `tf.data.Dataset` then my solution would be sufficient else there would be too many cases depending on the dimension size, the type of data etc. that would play a role in determining if it is batched or not.

Comment: @yudhiesh unfortunately I get "T5 fails"

Comment: Could you include the code?

Comment: @yudhiesh see my update

Comment: The code is not what I meant the but I realized I mistook `tf.data.Datasets` for `tensorflow_datasets`. My answer was meant for `tensorflow_datasets`.

Comment: How would you differentiate between a dataset that have elements of shape `(32,32)`, and a dataset of elements of shape `(32,)` with a batch size of `32`?

Comment: @Lescurel That's why my function accepts dataset instead of shape

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that the `tf.data.Dataset` API won't make the difference. It was a rhetorical question to show you that it's not possible to have a reliable method.

Comment: @Lescurel Can I turn on lazy evaluation? In that case does dataset object retain information on all previous calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list(range(48))).\
    batch(4).prefetch(1)
```

You can inspect the input dataset and see if it's a `BatchDataset`:

```
x._input_dataset.__class__.__name__
```

```
'BatchDataset'
```

It is, so it will have a `_batch_size` attribute:

```
x._input_dataset._batch_size
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=4>
```

Maybe the second last operation will not be the batching, so you may need to use `_input_dataset` iteratively to find the batch dataset, like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list(range(48))).\
    batch(4).prefetch(1).map(lambda x: x).cache()

x._input_dataset._input_dataset._input_dataset.__class__.__name__
```

```
'BatchDataset'
```

Answer (score 0):

So would the following solution work in all cases?

```py
def labels_from_dataset(dataset):
    if not isinstance(dataset, tf.data.Dataset):
      raise TypeError('dataset is not a tf.data.Dataset')

    input_dataset = dataset._input_dataset
    while not hasattr(input_dataset, '_batch_size') and hasattr(input_dataset, '_input_dataset'):
      input_dataset = input_dataset._input_dataset

    if hasattr(input_dataset, '_batch_size'):
      dataset = dataset.unbatch()

    y_labels = []
    for _, labels in dataset:
        y_labels.append(labels.numpy())

    return y_labels
```